# Is there a way to change DynamoDB table status from updating to active?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I ran two table update command consecutively on each table and now all of our tables are in continual update status. The first command added kms encryption using CMK. The second command set table replication. Did this through a script for 60 tables. Now all tables have been in continuous update status for about an hour. Not one table has done updating. These are non-production tables with little data in them. Looks like the kms key was applied successfully, but I dont see any global table settings. Looks like the replication command did not apply. What could possibly be wrong? If possible how can I get a dynamodb table back to active status?

Comment: How big are these tables? Encrypting everything  can take time. If you feel its too long may need to contact aws support to check why its stuck and to unstuck it.

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem on my local. I actually get an error when second command is run. No error generated when script is run in build server. Must have different version of the aws cli on build server.